# mysql query search for two conditions on two table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table, #1: row(int),id(int),type(int) 
and next one #2: row(int),id(int),visit(int)

I want to set a query to select all of items in table #2 which has type=1 in table #1.

How to do that ?

Comment: Do not clear your requirement Please explain proper what exactly you want ?

Comment: Which one column is foreign key between these two tables

Comment: @SunilPachlangia id

Comment: the  foreign key is id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go :

```
SEELCT row, id, visit FROM table2
INNER JOIN table1 USING(id)
WHERE table1.type = 1
```

Let me explain the `INNER JOIN table1 USING(id)` :
The `JOIN` means you collapse table rows of the table1 to the table2, 
`INNER` excludes the rows where no id from the table1 match the id from the table2, and finally `USING(id)` ask the engine to use the `id` column to match rows.